# Como eu mudo a cor de fundo de um item JFoenix Combobox?

Tags: java, css, javafx, material-design

Eu estou tendo problema com cores no JFoenix. Meu programa tem essa paleta amarela, cinza e branca, mas todos objetos estão em azul. Como os itens desta combobox:

[image: Combobox azul]

Eu tentei adicionar isto ao arquivo `jfx-combo-box.css`:

```
.jfx-combo-box{
   -jfx-focus-color: #f2e668;
   -jfx-unfocus-color: #4d4d4d;
   -fx-prompt-text-fill: #4d4d4d;
 }
.jfx-combo-box .label {
   -fx-background-color:  WHITE;
   -fx-text-fill: RED;
 }
```

Porém não funcionou. Este problema também ocorre no meu JFXListView.

Comment: Stack em português, jovem, traduz sua pergunta ai.

Comment: chegou a ver [essa issue](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/411) ?